# How to prepare this legacy class for importing to VueJs application?

Tags: javascript, oop, vue.js

I have some legacy custom class in my old application. This class is defined like so:

```
/** @namespace MyClass */
"use strict";

var MyClass = (function () {
    var Constr = {};

    Constr.func1 = function () {...};
    ...
    Constr.funcN = function () {...};

    return Constr;

}());
```

In my application I import this class in a old fashioned way:

```
<head>
    <script src="./static/MyClass.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

Now I try VueJS framework and love it. What I want to achieve is to import my old legacy class to my new application. I do not like to import it in index.html in an old manner, but I want to do it in my custom Vue component. So, in my `TestComponent.vue` I want to be able to do something like:

```
import MyClass from './static/MyClass.js' // or from './assets/MyClass.js' ?
```

But I'm not sure, how can I do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to `import` it, you have to `export` the class from `myClass.js`. No need for an IIFE, because you'll be in module scope, not global scope, so no need to worry about global pollution:

```
// MyClass.js
export default const Constr = {};
Constr.func1 = function () {...};
Constr.funcN = function () {...};
```

That said, what you have here is just a *plain object* with properties, not a class, so it'd probably be best not to call it `MyClass`.

Comment: I will check it in a minute!

Comment: And what is the proper way to import this object, if it is in assets folder?

Comment: The way you're already doing it - your syntax is trying to import the default export from the module, so the module is using `export default`. `import MyClass from './assets/MyClass.js'`

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to export your class.

```
export default MyClass
```

Should do the trick. This needs to be added inside your script. After that you can just import it. The imported var can have any name, it is not constrained to MyClass.